# Using constructors to init instance vars subclass PFObject

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, subclassing, pfobject

I am working on implementing a subclass of PFObject called Event, in Swift. I followed the subclassing guide in Parse's docs, but I don't understand how and where to write the code that adds data to the ivars. Below is my what I have in my class so far, including the ivars.

```
@NSManaged var name:String
@NSManaged var time:NSDate
@NSManaged var favorite:Bool
@NSManaged var moderator: String
@NSManaged var speakers: [String] 

@NSManaged var slides: PFFile?

@NSManaged var files: [PFFile]?

override class func initialize() {
    var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }        
}

class func parseClassName() -> String! {
    return "Event"
}
```

Normally, I would implement an init() constructor or something similar. However, I realized that the data would already be contained in the PFObject's dictionary when it is fetched from the server. Where would I put the code to copy across and put this data in the instance vars from the PFObject's dictionary? This is presuming that I would instantiate the object via a query and fetch from the server and not locally using the object() method.

Comment: You don't. That's why those properties are taged with @NSManaged. You can use this properties to get and set data on you object, it will get from and update the dictionary containing the data automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment by deadbeef above, I realized that I can just use Swift's getters and setters for computed properties to read and write values from the PFObject's data dictionary. 
For example a property that I intend to have as read-only:

```
var name:String
{
    return self["name"] as String
}
```

And a property I intend to have as read-write

```
var favorite:Bool 
{
    get {
        return self["favorite"] as Bool
    }
    set(value) {
        self["favorite"] = value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to copy manually.
That's the Parse framework job. The objects will be populated with data after a fetch.